# Which symbol is best interpreted as describing a social interaction?

Tags: interaction-design, interface, symbols

I am working on a project of social media like website and I have to symbolize the interaction between two peers in a small space - equivalent to a standard FB profile picture for instance.
The question is simple, what is a commonly understood way to symbolize an interaction between two peers (or a relation) without using plain words to explain it?

Comment: Hi Pierre, welcome to ux.se. I'm not sure I understand exactly what the 'interaction' *is* that you are trying to symbolize. Is it a conversation (IM), or exchange of documents, or a ping or notification of some kind. If you *were* using plain words to explain it - what would those words be?

Comment: Hi Roger, thanks for the help. Th einteraction I am talking about is a real life interaction just as when two people go on holidays together or just like you helping here. 
Therefore, depending on the context, the interaction can be Roger helped Pierre or Luke and Leia went on holidays together. 
Once this interaction is translated into a post, one user may re-post it. Then I am looking for a general way to signify this re-post.
I hope that's descriptive enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If people have avatars, you could show both avatars beside each other. Nothing more. Do not try and connect the avatars as this may be confused or even misconstrued! If there are no avatars for someone then use a default head/shoulder blank avatar.

Let whitespace do the separation between the avatars and the description.

Take Trello as an example, where several users may be *attached* to a card. The important thing is that people are not related directly to each other - they are both only directly related to the event itself.

This example is taken from the [Trello public development board](https://trello.com/b/nC8QJJoZ/trello-development)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have several ways people could relate:

- ***Handshake***
- ***Synergy***
- ***Conversation***
- ***Social***

Images below are illustrated below.

*Note: These were are all taken from Google Images, so **credit is not mine** and some are stock photos. They are just examples.*

---

## Handshake

[image: handshake]

## Synergy

[image: synergy]

## Conversation

[image: conversation]

## Social

[image: social]